# recursive display is not showing right format

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Something wrong with my IF-ELSE statement and my dumb brain cannot figure out what the heck it is!

If I run the below code on its own it shows each directory and files in there in the below format:

```
get-childitem E:\LogArchive -recurse | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt 60}
```

Format of output:

```
    Directory: E:\LogArchive\W3SVC100


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-----        29/03/2007     15:03        663 ex070329.log.gz
-----        30/03/2007     15:44        860 ex070330.log.gz
-----        03/04/2007     13:41        354 ex070403.log.gz
-----        05/04/2007     14:00        704 ex070405.log.gz
-----        10/04/2007     17:56        921 ex070410.log.gz
-----        11/04/2007     14:55        987 ex070411.log.gz
-----        12/04/2007     15:12        539 ex070412.log.gz
```

However, when this is run in a code it shows as the below, WITHOUT all the folder structure and dates etc:

```
W3SVC100
W3SVC102
W3SVC105
W3SVC106
W3SVC1108492480
W3SVC112
W3SVC116
W3SVC118
W3SVC1209046175
W3SVC123110214
W3SVC1262336480
W3SVC127
W3SVC134
W3SVC134239081
W3SVC137
W3SVC139
W3SVC145
W3SVC147
W3SVC1499983181
W3SVC15
```

How do I get the first results when the below script is run - so show all the modified date, last write time etc . I am currently inputting a message to the user if no files are found in the date range then a message is displayed - however, if it did find anyfiles then display them as listed in the first output type.......

I actually think the fault is on this line but cannot figure out how to amend this:

```
if ( $runchilditem.lastwritetime -gt DateToCompare)
```

......In fact - I want to put the output to CSV - any ideas how I can do this?

CODE:

```
$path = Read-Host "Please enter the path of the folder yu wish to check - this will check sub-folders as well"
Write-Host "`n"
$days = Read-Host "Please enter in number of DAYS you wish to go back"

$DateToCompare = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)

$runningtrue = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt $DateToCompare}

Write-Host "`n"
$runchilditem = @(Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse)
    if ( $runchilditem.lastwritetime -gt DateToCompare) 
        {
            Write-Host "No Files Matching Date Criteria Found"
        }
    else
        {
            $runningtrue
        }
```

Comment: So you just want to display the files more recent than the date specified or display a message if none are more recent?

Comment: Hi - yeah, so if a file is more than say 90 days old then display those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your need, here is how I would do it:

```
$path = Read-Host 'Path'
[int]$dayDiff = Read-Host 'Number of days to go back'
$offset = $dayDiff * -1
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays($offset)}
if(($files.Count -eq 0) -OR ($files -eq $null)){
    'There are no files after {0} in {1}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays($offset), $path
}else{
    $files
    $files | Export-CSV C:\PATH\TO\FILE.csv -NoTypeInfo
}
```

Comment: nearly there I think - I get an error when I run this with the * in the command. I just want to display the result of files (and which folder those files reside in) that are say MORE than (or equal to) 90 days old.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing it off the top of my head. See if the edit is what you needed.